# During lvalue conversion, why is the & so special and | never mentioned?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, c11

Section [§6.3.2.1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (page 72) explains that

- An `lvalue` means an object i.e. piece of memory.
- During evaluation of expressions, the objects are converted to their values i.e. become no longer objects. Notable exceptions are the left operands of `=`, `&`, `.`, `++`, `--`, `sizeof`.
- Arrays are generally converted to a constant pointer to their first element. Again the operand of `&` is an exception.
- Functions are implicitly converted to pointers to functions. Except when the target of the unary `&`.

Why is the unary `&` so special? Why is the unary `|` never mentioned?

Comment: @Jens Gustedt, OMG, you answered my question. I was thinking & as binary AND, using the word unary without realizing it's meaning. Hmmm. So they are talking about he "address of" operator!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know were your problem lies, but most of the assertions that you are given are at least partially wrong

- An lvalue means an object i.e. piece of memory.

an object is not necessarily a piece of memory, notable exceptions are variables that are declared with `register`.  An object is an identifiable place with a well defined life time and type.

- During evaluation of expressions, the objects are converted to their
  values i.e. become no longer objects.

This is stating things bizarrely. During the evaluation of an expression an object is ... evaluated. The object itself is unchanged

- Notable exceptions are the left operands of =, &, ., ++, --, sizeof.

You are mixing very different kinds of operators here. How the value of a `sizeof` operator would be an lvalue, I can't follow. You probably mean that the lvalue conversion doesn't apply to them? This is simply because these operators act on the object (change the object) or need properties of the object (and not of a potentially converted value).

- Arrays are generally converted to a constant pointer to their first
  element. Again the operand of & is an exception.

The `sizeof` operator here is another.

- Functions are implicitly converted to pointers to functions. Except
  when the target of the unary &.

... where they are just converted explicitly.

Comment: Thanks. Your definition of object is very clear. And your last point answers my silly question.